# Building new JSON from existing one

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

I want to build an new `JSON` from existing one. The source has sections and rubrics that I no longer need for a listing. The new object called 'items' should have an array of the items.

The final JSON should be sorted by attribute 'name' and look like

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "id": 10000006,
      "name": "Boah"
    },
    {
      "id": 10000013,
      "name": "Gut"
    },
    {
      "id": 10000003,
      "name": "Ipsum"
    },
    {
      "id": 10000001,
      "name": "Lorem"
    },
    {
      "id": 10000005,
      "name": "Lorum"
    },
    {
      "id": 10000004,
      "name": "Name"
    },
    {
      "id": 10000002,
      "name": "Stet"
    }
  ]
}
```

For building the new JSON I get this source:

```
{
  "sections": [
    {
      "name": "FooBar",
      "rubrics": [
        {
          "name": "Foo",
          "items": [
            {
              "id": 10000001,
              "name": "Lorem"
            },
            {
              "id": 10000002,
              "name": "Stet"
            },
            {
              "id": 10000003,
              "name": "Ipsum"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Bar",
          "items": [
            {
              "id": 10000004,
              "name": "Name"
            },
            {
              "id": 10000005,
              "name": "Lorum"
            },
            {
              "id": 10000006,
              "name": "Boah"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "BlahBloob",
      "rubrics": [
        {
          "name": "Bla",
          "items": [
            {
              "id": 10000013,
              "name": "Gut"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Bloob",
          "items": [
            {
              "id": 10000014,
              "name": "Name"
            },
            {
              "id": 10000015,
              "name": "Lorem"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

What do you think? How can I do this with plain `JavaScript` or maybe `TypeScript`?

Thanks for reading and have time for my question. And thanks for reply in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go. You just need to iterate over each rubric of each section of your source to get the items. At the end, sort your list of items by items, and you're done.

This example uses ES6 syntax, but it's easy to convert it to ES5 if needed.

```
function extractItems(source) {
  const items = [];

  for (const section of source.sections) {
    for (const rubric of section.rubrics) {
      items.push(...rubric.items);
    }
  }

  items.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name));

  return { items };
}
```

Comment: Yeah! Thank you very much for pointing in the right direction. I just have to iterate one more. `for (const item of rubric.items)`. That's it!

Comment: About your edit for the iterating over rubric.items, it's not needed, but it depends on your browser/nodejs version. Syntax `items.push(...rubric.items)` is called "spread operator", and works fine, but it's one of the latest ES6 features implemented by engines. I changed the implementation to use `.concat`. It avoids an extra for-loop, and is way more efficient performance-wise :)

Comment: Aurelien: What do you think about the solution of @toskv ?

Comment: I love functional programming ! This is my preferred version. I often go with for-loops as I work with Big Data, and it's way faster (`map` creates a new array and populates it, whereas for-loops just iterate over the initial array). But for normal arrays (thousands of items), it's perfect!

Comment: @AurélienRibon I have to agree your solution is faster and uses far less memory. It would also be a bit easier to understand when read. :)

Comment: It depends. I really love functional programming, so I would read yours faster, but it requires a bit of practice indeed. Imperative programming is more common (depends on user background), but it's also more verbose and indented. In this simple algorithm, it's okay, but you often end up breaking the function into multiple sub functions...

Comment: Also, a big advantage of functional programming is that it relies on functions. V8 (chrome, nodejs) optimizes functions at lot as soon as they are called often (more than 2 times). If my `extractItems` function is only called once on a super big array, it will be slow. If you call it 3 times on the same array, the third time will be 10x to 100x faster. Magic of Crankshaft/Turbofan optimizers :)

Comment: @toskv Do you think Aureliens answer is the right one?

Comment: they both solve the issue, they just do it in different ways and provide different benefits. It's up to you to decide which one fits your problem best. :)

Comment: @AlexanderSchmidt I guess the question that you have to ask yourself is what do you value more? Speed or conciseness?

Comment: @toskv yes, this is the right question. I prefer more readable code, too. So Aureliens answer is my favorite. Your answer is still more elegant. ;) Thank you both for your time.

Answer (score 2):

A more functional approach use **map** and **reduce** to pick the rubrics and merge them.

```js
data.sections
  .map(section => section.rubrics) // get rubrics
  .reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b)) // merge rubrics
  .map(rubric => rubric.items) // get items from each rubric
  .reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b)) // merge items
  .sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name)); // sort
```

Comment: This is very elegant. Thank you very much. I consider to make this the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
function(oldObj) {
    var newObj = {
        "items": []
    };

    oldObj.sections.forEach(function(section) {
        section.rubrics.forEach(function(rubric) {
            rubric.items.forEach(function(item) {
                newObj.items.push(item);
            });
        });
    });

    newObj.items = newObj.items.sort(function(a, b) {
        if (a.name < b.name) { return -1; }
        if (a.name > b.name) { return 1;  }
        return 0;
    });
    return newObj;
}
```

And simply use `JSON.parse()` and `JSON.stringify()` to convert JSON to and from objects.

Comment: Yeah! This works out of the box. Thank you! Just prefer the solution of @Aurélien Ribon for the ES6 syntax.

Answer (score 0):

**It might help you**

```js
var data ={
 "sections": [
{
"name": "FooBar",
"rubrics": [{"name": "Foo", "items": [{"id": 10000001,"name": "Lorem"}, {"id": 10000002,"name": "Stet"}, {"id": 10000003,"name": "Ipsum"}]
}, {
   "name": "Bar",
   "items": [{
    "id": 10000004,
    "name": "Name"
   }, {
    "id": 10000005,
    "name": "Lorum"
   }, {
    "id": 10000006,
    "name": "Boah"
   }]
  }]
 }, {
  "name": "BlahBloob",
  "rubrics": [{
   "name": "Bla",
   "items": [{
    "id": 10000013,
    "name": "Gut"
   }]
  }, {
   "name": "Bloob",
   "items": [{
    "id": 10000014,
    "name": "Name"
   }, {
    "id": 10000015,
    "name": "Lorem"
   }]
  }]
 }]
};
var itemObj = {};
var itemArr = [];
var sections = data.sections;
for(var i=0;i<sections.length;i++)
{ 
  for(var j=0;j<sections[i].rubrics.length;j++){    
    for(var k=0;k<sections[i].rubrics[j].items.length;k++){      
      var itemObj;
      itemObj['id'] = sections[i].rubrics[j].items[k].id;
      itemObj['name'] = sections[i].rubrics[j].items[k].name;      
      itemArr.push(itemObj);
    }
  }
}
var finalObj = {"items":itemArr};
console.log(finalObj);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MWSeg/607/)

Comment: Thank you for your efforts.